# How can i convert string to array of object json in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i just create a migration like this

```
def change
    add_column :articles, : information, :json,
               default: '[{ "type:c":"12", "temperature":12 }]', null: false
end
```

i just migrated that table

right now, to create a new article, i am sending this in my request with postman, **i am sending properly the 'information' as string?**

```
{
     "section":"139",
     "information":"[{ type:c, temperature:9 }]" //string
 }
```

so far every thing is ok

now i want to get the param information as a array not string

**I want to convert information in an array of json object, how can i do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in two ways.

```
require 'yaml'

input_params = {"section":"139","information":"[{ type: c, temperature: 9 }]"}
#=> {"section"=>"139", "information"=>"[{ type: c, temperature: 9 }]"}

YAML.load(input_params['information'])
#=> [{"type"=>"c", "temperature"=>9}]
```

or If you want to use `JSON.parse` then `input_params` should be as below:

```
require 'json' 

input_params = {"section"=> "139", "information" =>'[{ "type":"c", "temperature":"9" }]'}
#=> {"section"=>"139", "information"=>"[{ \"type\":\"c\", \"temperature\":\"9\" }]"}

JSON.parse(input_params['information'])
#=> [{"type"=>"c", "temperature"=>9}]
```

I hope this will help you